# Nginx - how to proxy_pass particular url to a different host while keeping context?

Tags: nginx

I have a fairly simple nginx conf for a front-end and backend application:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name nginx_server;
        port_in_redirect off;

        location / {
                root /dir/html;
                index index.html index.htm;
        }

        location  /api/ {
                proxy_pass         http://my-api:8080/;
        }
}
```

My main host is https and this works fine. When I hit `https://myapp.com/api/a/b/c`, my backend receives `/a/b/c`, which is what I want.

Now, I want to send the requests to a particular /api context to a different server:

```
 location  /api/a/b {
                rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass         http://another-api:8080;
        }
```

So now, if I hit `https://myapp.com/api/a/b?param=1` I want to hit `http://another-api:8080/a/b?param=1` and also `https://myapp.com/api/a/b/c/d` should hit `http://another-api:8080/a/b/c/d`

This is working when I test using Postman, but for some reason, in Chrome, when my frontend app tries to hit `https://myapp.com/api/a/b/c/d` I get a console error: `(blocked:mixed-content)`

How can I fix this?

Comment: This error means that some page content received via HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS. Look at the network tab of DevTools to see what requests are made with HTTP and what source originates such requests.

Comment: My nginx have ssl configured and I am proxying to http hosts. The location /api/ does this and it works. I am not sure why the other location does not. Both are https to http.